# Trying to enforce ASP.NET core MVC to use HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-mvc

I have tried to follow a few tutorials and this is what I've got:

adding to ConfigureServices,

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            options.HttpsPort = 44300;
        });
```

adding `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`
to Configure method.

running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` in the cmd to get the following message:
[image]

then I went to the Certificates and moved it from Personal folder to Trusted Root Certificate Authorities.

this is how the projects properties looks like:

[image]

and that's what I get when I run it:

[image]

no idea where to go from here, any advice?

EDIT------------------------------
[image]

also enabled SSL:

[image]

Comment: Your app isn't listening on an "SSL" port. You can see that the "Enable SSL" checkbox is disabled, so the app is _only_ listening on the non-SSL port `51769`. `options.HttpsPort = 44300` just tells your app where to redirect to, but there's nothing listening on that port.

Comment: Hey, thank you for explaining, I enabled SSL but still cannot reach the page, I edited the question at the bottom

Comment: you enabled ssl in port 44367, but your http redirection option is port 44300. have you tried directly visit https://localhost:44367?

Comment: yes @ElendilZheng-MSFT still the same output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating my own Certificate using the IIS Manager and all of the settings in my original post making sure the PORT is the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the **sslPort** in your **launchsettings.json** file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, I edited my question with pictures to show that I added the port property & it still doesn't work